# Repeatedly splitting strings in python

Tags: python, string, split

I am looking to make a function to break a string into a list of str by breaking it at various punctuation points (e.g. , ! ?) that I specify. I know I should used the .split() function with the specific punctuation, however I can't figure out how to get iterate running the split with each punctuation character specified to produce a single list of str with made up from the original str split at every punctuation character.

Answer (score 3):

To split with multiple delimiters, you should use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split):

```
import re
pattern = r"[.,!?]"  # etc.
new = re.split(pattern, your_current_string)
```

Putting that in function form should be simple enough.

Comment: Using your method I get a list of empty strings. `re.split(pattern, "Hello!I'd like, to say something. 'World'.")` returns '["", "", "", "", "", "", ""]'

Comment: @bvidal That's because I forgot to escape the full stop (which meant it was splitting on everything); thanks for telling me. Try it again now.

Comment: It's probably a better idea to write the regex directly (`pattern = r"[.,!?]"`), or use `re.escape`: `pattern='|'.join(map(re.escape, delimiters))`.

Comment: @YannVernier I'd say that's definitely a better idea. Edited.